# x86 assembly rcl al,1 is not clearing carry flag when al equals zero

Tags: assembly, x86

The title sums it up.

If the carry flag is previously set when the rcl instruction is envoke and al is zero then the the top bit (0) is not moved into carry.

The follow codes demonstrates:

```
mov al,0
stc
setc byte ptr [before]
rcl al,1 ; rotate left one bit through carry flag (multiply by 2 once)
setc byte ptr [after]
```

So the output:

```
before = 01
after = 01
```

The carry flag is not cleared as it would be expected.  Reading the Intel manual:

```
The shift arithmetic left (SAL) and shift logical left (SHL) instructions perform the same operation; they shift the
bits in the destination operand to the left (toward more significant bit locations). For each shift count, the most
significant bit of the destination operand is shifted into the CF flag, and the least significant bit is cleared (see
Figure 7-7 in the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 1).
```

To me it appears that if the source value is zero then nothing at all is done and this is not correct!

Comment: This works correctly in a [sample program](https://gist.github.com/fuzxxl/aee9a4c28ab6c2fdd8e9998ba8750ebf), giving me `before = 1, after = 0, al = 1`. Make sure your debugger has stopped past the last line where you check the content of the variables.

Comment: You can also use `adc al,al` as a more-efficient alternative to `rcl al,1`.  It writes all the flags instead of having to merge to leave some unmodified.  Anyway, this doesn't look like a [mcve] because the problem is in how you're examining the results or something.  Otherwise (not plausible) your CPU is broken or (more plausible) your assembler is broken.  Perhaps you're on MacOS with a buggy NASM generating incorrect addressing modes?

Comment: In the end I managed this going on VS2015 but couldn't get it going when porting to VScode with jwasm.  Turned out I had a bug (in the calling C code) that VS2015 was avoiding. Yeah so corrected the C code and all good and the rcl is working as documented.

Comment: @WallyZ Cool!  Please post your solution as an answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent cause of my problems (and there were three) was the C optimiser cutting out code because it was unaware that the assembly code had any effect on certain variables.

(My code examples pertain to a 6809/6309 CPU emulator)

I'll summarise the three issues.

1. The rcl assembly instruction appeared to be NOT setting the carry flag.

   (Documented in this post)
2. The assembly code would run 100-1000 times slower when the C code was compiled with optimisation.

   (Example not possible)
3. Certain code needed obfuscating in order to make the code work at all.

The following code:

```c
static void(*JmpVec1[256])(void) = { ... };
...
unsigned char memByte = MemRead8(PC_REG++);
JmpVec1[memByte](); // Execute instruction pointed to by byte @ PC_REG
CycleCounter += instcycl1[memByte]; // Add instruction cycles
```

Would only work if the following code was used :

```c
static void(*JmpVec1[256])(void) = { ... };
...
unsigned char memByte = MemRead8(PC_REG++);
if (memByte == 0x34) // Just doesn't like instruction 0x34 Pushs register_list
{
    JmpVec1[memByte](); // Execute instruction pointed to by PC_REG
}
else
{
    JmpVec1[memByte](); // Execute instruction pointed to by PC_REG
}
CycleCounter += instcycl1[memByte]; // Add instruction cycles
```

Since the C code has no idea what any of the 437 emulated instructions are doing or what effects those instructions have why it chose instruction 0x34 to stop working is a mystery.

What fixed the problem and allowed me to remove the obfuscated code and allowed me to re-enable C optimisations was making the CycleCounter (int) variable volatile.

Fixed all my issues!!!

This issue was further compounded because there is no disassembly support in vscode making the the debugging of assembly routines extremely difficult.

If anyone is using a good C / assembly IDE on Linux please drop a comment.

Comment: If you're compiling with GCC and generating x86 machine code in C arrays, you need to tell the optimizer that data will be executed as code.  See [How does \_\_builtin\_\_\_clear\_cache work?](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/85964322) .  e.g. example in [How do I call hex data stored in an array with inline assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56213418) of actually using `__builtin___clear_cache` properly.

Comment: GDB works for debugging asm; it has a disassembly mode.  There might be some front-ends that also work for asm, like maybe GDBGUI, I forget.  Even if you have to go outside your IDE, having a debugger with a disassembly mode is *essential* if you're doing runtime code-gen.

Comment: Or if you're using GNU C inline asm, likely you have incorrect constraints so you're stepping on the compiler's toes in the delicate dance between your code and optimizer.

Comment: Or if you're calling stand-alone asm functions, then you're probably violating the calling convention and stepping on the compiler's toes by clobbering some registers, or memory above your stack frame.  **Changing the compiler-generated asm in the calling function with apparently-unrelated changes is totally consistent with your asm violating its "contract" with the compiler.**  The solution proposed in this answer is totally a happens-to-work hack, not a real solution that will work in general for other people.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes. The x86 is not in the C array. The array is list of assembly function pointers.  I have forced the C compiler to use msabi when making calls between C and assembly functions.  I believe I have setup the x86 stack correctly as per recommendations however I could have made mistakes.  I chose msabi because it compiles under both Linux and Mingw.

Comment: Yeah, after the first couple comments I noticed you mentioned VS2015 or something.  My last comment (about calling stand-alone asm functions) is covering that case.  You're probably destroying a value in a register the caller expects you to preserve.  e.g. in Windows x64, RBX, RDI, RSI, RBP, RSP, and R12-R15 are all call-preserved.  So are XMM6-15, IIRC.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes. Thanks, I understand that convention and I was respecting those registers. My problem turned out to be two things: The C compiler was optimizing away code it shouldn't have until I gave it some volatile hints. And two I was accessing C global variables with the wrong size on occasion (my mistake).

Comment: If you needed `volatile` you're probably doing something wrong.  (Or at least violating the ABI / accessing data you couldn't with a C function at that point, whether you call that "wrong" or not).  I don't see why you'd need `volatile` on globals when the compiler can see the function calls, or on any locals that have had their address passed to other functions.  A non-inline function call already has to be a memory barrier for having globals in sync in memory.  Unless you're multi-threading?